# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

[Solana Stack Exchange's first moderator election](https://solana.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: C.OG]

[image: Jacob Creech]

[image: Joe C]

They will make up [the site's initial crew of moderators](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4816974386298880).